# How to iterate through two Arraylists simultaneously and making a "couple" of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've playing around with Generics and have a light problem here in my code. My question is how how to iterate through two Arraylists simultaneously (without `Iterator`) and at the same time making a "couple" by getting objects from those two arraylists in the method `combine()`? I've commented examples in the code also how the output should look like.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Answer {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test_combine();
    }
    public static void test_combine(){
          System.out.println("TESTING COMBINE");
          ArrayList<String> theStrings = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Hi","wow","Nuts"}));
          // [Hi, wow, Nuts]
          ArrayList<Integer> theInts    = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{15, -4, 42}));
          // [15, -4, 42]
          ArrayList<Pair2<String,Integer>> stringInts = combine(theStrings,theInts);
          System.out.println(stringInts);
          // [(Hi,15), (wow,-4), (Nuts,42)]

          ArrayList<Double> theDoubs = new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(new Double[]{1.23, 42.1, 99.0, -2.1}));
          // [1.23, 42.1, 99.0, -2.1]
          ArrayList<Character> theChars = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'Z','a','!','?'}));
          // [Z, a, !, ?]
          ArrayList<Pair2<Double,Character>> doubChars = combine(theDoubs, theChars);
          System.out.println(doubChars);
          // [(1.23, Z), (42.1, a), (99.0, !), (-2.1, ?)]    
        }  



        public static <X,Y>ArrayList<Pair2<X,Y>> combine(ArrayList<X> xs, ArrayList<Y> ys)
        {
            ArrayList<Pair2<X,Y>> newValues = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i < xs.size() && i < ys.size(); i++)
            {
                newValues.add(xs.get(i), ys.get(i));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: what is Pair2?? you need to write `newValues.add(new Pair2(xs.get(i), ys.get(i)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your posted code, this

```
newValues.add(xs.get(i), ys.get(i));
```

should be something like

```
newValues.add(new Pair2(xs.get(i), ys.get(i)));
```

Assuming your `Pair2` has a constructor that can take `X, Y`.

Comment: Could you please explain why you included new Pair2?? I appreciate it

Comment: Because `newValues` is an `ArrayList<Pair2>`.... all that can be added to it is instances of the class `Pair2`. You create an instance of the class `Pair2` by using `new Pair2`. (Or, maybe a Factory or Builder).